# Symfony deserialize object with a constructor

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, deserialization

I'm working on a project using Symfony with ApiPlatform and MongoDB. In my DataProvider I'm getting data back from an aggregation builder that is returning an object of class '\ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\MongoDbOdm\Paginator'. I need to serialize the data to store in a Redis cache, and deserialize it when pulling from the cache. I can serialize it just fine and see it in the cache, but when I try to deserialize it I'm getting the following error.

> Cannot create an instance of "\ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\MongoDbOdm\Paginator" from serialized data because its constructor requires parameter "mongoDbOdmIterator" to be present.

Any guidance on how to pass the mongoDbOdmIterator to the constructor, or any better way of serializing/deserializing this object? Code below:

```
$encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$data = $this->getCollectionResults($aggregationBuilder, $resourceClass, $operationName, $context);
$serialized = $this->serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

...

$data = $this->serializer->deserialize($serialized, '\ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\MongoDbOdm\Paginator', 'json');
```

Comment: have you tried the default constructor like mentioned [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-serializer-improvements#default-constructor-arguments-for-denormalization)?

Comment: Tried that but can't figure out how to get a mongoDbOdmIterator to pass to the constructor. Won't let me instantiate a new Iterator() and can't find any method to get the iterator.